# Getting distinct list of ID's in CoreData

Tags: iphone, core-data, distinct-values

What's the most efficient way to perform this query on a CoreData table?  To use the standard employees database model -- I want DISTINCT department ID's for all departments that contain employees with job-description "chef."  As it happens, there is only a single table (Employees) relevant here -- I don't actually have a departments table, just department ID's that are repeated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the schema you describe, I would execute a fetch with a predicate (format string) like `@"jobDescription LIKE 'chef'"` and then use key-value coding to get the unique values from the resulting array:

```
[result valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfValues.departmentID"];
```

or create a set:

```
NSSet *deparmentIDs = [NSSet setWithArray:[result valueForKey:@"departmentID"]];
```

Depending on the size of the problem (how many employees), doing the final step in-memory may prove prohibitive. At this point, you'll have to create a Department entity and do the work to make sure you connect appropriate employees to each department. Then you can do a fetch of Departments with a predicate (format string) like `@"ANY employees.jobDescription LIKE 'chef'"` to get the departments with chef employees.

Comment: Thanks! The second of these suggested solutions worked for me, but I decided to refactor to avoid expensive operations like this.